# Missing HDD space after diskutil command

Tags: macos, partition, mojave, apfs

I wanted to merge 2 partitions `disk0s2`(unused space) and `disk0s4`(OS volume)

My disk looked like this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                500.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         199.3 GB   disk0s4
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                300.0 GB   disk0s5
```

Somewhere here I found a solution so I ran the command

> sudo diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s2

But then the next command

> sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s4 0

Gave error:

> Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space

So now it looks like this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         199.3 GB   disk0s4
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                300.0 GB   disk0s5
```

> gpt show disk0

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   977979728         
   978389368   389234312      2  GPT part - 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1367623680   585901455      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

[image]

The best would be if I could make the main volume to the full space available, but if it's  too difficult it would be enough to have that 500Gb as a separate volume as it was.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your free space is before the container, not after it. In order to expand it, you need free physical space after the container. You could try using a live CD (such as GNU Parted) to physically relocate the blocks of the APFS container to start at 409640, but this is perilous and should not be done without a backup.

Comment: Do you know for sure if GNU Parted handles moving APFS partitions?

Comment: Since it's just physically moving the blocks around on disk, the filesystem in use isn't relevant.

Comment: I agree with you. Now you just have to convince the authors of GNU Parted that that should be true.

Comment: Oh man, they block it? That's bogus. Maybe it's time to do a custom build? Surely there are other free tools that will do the job, that's just the first one that popped up in my mind.

Comment: Hold on. I am checking. To be sure, are you referring to [GNU Parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) or the [GNOME Partition Editor](https://gparted.org)? GNU Parted seems to only have a command-line interface, while the GNOME Partition Editor has a graphical interface.

Comment: You could also do it with `dd`, but you'll also need to create a new GPT entry for the "new" partition. Make it the exact same size as the source partition! (Then expand it later with Disk Utility or `diskutil`.) Warning: this'll be really easy to mess up and lose data -- make sure you have good backups of everything you care about, on both the macOS and Windows partitions (preferably multiple backups of each).